# How can I determine the actual font name of a Type 3 PDF Font using iText7?

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext, itext7

I am trying to read all fonts used in a PDF using iText7. In order to do so I have created an `IEventListener` which reads the fonts from a `TextRenderInfo` as:

```
private class FontReader : IEventListener
{
    public ICollection<string> Fonts { get; }

    public FontReader()
    {
        Fonts = new List<string>();
    }

    public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        if (!(data is TextRenderInfo)) return;

        var font = ((TextRenderInfo) data).GetFont();
        var fontName = font.GetFontProgram().GetFontNames().GetFontName();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fontName) && !Fonts.Contains(fontName))
        {
            Fonts.Add(fontName);
        }
    }

    public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
    {
        return new HashSet<EventType> {EventType.RENDER_TEXT};
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine and allows me to read all Type 1 fonts. But calling `GetFontProgram().GetFontNames().GetFontName();` on a Type 3 font returns null.

Viewing the fonts in Acrobat Reader does show me a name for the Type 3 fonts though (see screenshot). How can I find this name through iText7 in C#?

[image: Type 3 font name in Acrobat Reader]

Comment: Hi, can you attach the sample PDF to reproduce?

Comment: @AlexeySubach Unfortunately I can't because they are confidential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the corresponding PDF object and fetch the font name from it with `var fontName = font.GetPdfObject().GetAsName(PdfName.Name)` instruction.

Full code example:

```
private class FontReader : IEventListener
{
    public ICollection<string> Fonts { get; }

    public FontReader()
    {
        Fonts = new List<string>();
    }

    public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        if (!(data is TextRenderInfo)) return;

        var font = ((TextRenderInfo) data).GetFont();
        var fontName = font.GetPdfObject().GetAsName(PdfName.Name)
    }

    public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
    {
        return new HashSet<EventType> {EventType.RENDER_TEXT};
    }
}
```

Comment: The **Name** entry is optional. Another (also optional) position to look for the font name is the **FontDescriptor**.

Comment: This works for me. At least for Type 3 PDF Fonts. So I first check if I have a value for `font.GetFontProgram().GetFontNames().GetFontName()` and if not I try `font.GetPdfObject().GetAsName(PdfName.Name).GetValue()`.